# Special properties of "vibrant" spline-functions

Tags: polynomials, na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, splines

While checking an idea about knot-placement for spline interpolation, I needed to find a way to calculate splines, that are strictly monotone between adjacent pairs of knots and for which every knot is a local minimum or maximum; I called those splines "vibrant" (another option would have been to call them "bang bang") splines.

As it turned out, those kind of splines are especially easy to calculate in the cubic case: "simply" join adjacent pairs of knots with the portion between the two extrema of appropriate cubic polynomials and, fix the value of the second derivative at the knots to the same value (e.g. to $1$); those conditions are sufficient to calculate the spline between two knots independent from the other knots.

**Question:**
have those vibrant splines already been encountered or investigated?